# Various logins don't work across SE sites, and can only log in from one single device

Tags: support, login

I have an account I've been using for over ten years, and it seems something has changed, perhaps more than once, in that period relating to how to log into the site.

I seem to have several login credentials in my profile on one of the sites. Setting the passwords all to the same password and the interface verifying they are all the same, I can still only use one of the credentials and it is for an email address I no longer have access to (I previously updated to the new email address BEFORE losing access to the address, but SE seems not to acknowledge this as a valid address for logging into SE).

I have one single device I can log into using the no longer functioning email address using any browser of my choosing, even ones that have never before been used to log in. Using the exact credentials on a different device I cannot log in. I can pass all the robot tests, but no matter what I do, the other device cannot log in.

Is there any way to set my login credentials for the email address that is currently functioning (it also seems to affect where password resets get sent) and is there a way to log in using a valid credential on a different device?

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be that I needed to add another login using the same credentials that had already been configured, then click the link in the confirmation email for the "new" login credentials and now I can use the credentials to log in.